# Getting Address from Google Map (Reverse Geocoding)

Tags: google-maps, e-commerce, reverse-geocoding, street-address

I have a online shop and people buy products and we send a products to their address , but sometimes customers enter a bad address and we couldn't find the destination.

I want to show a Google map in address form then customer locate their address on the map and finally address of that point fetched from Google map.

Is Google offers this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this service is known as [reverse geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#ReverseGeocoding).
And it's actually quite simple to implement. Assuming you get lat and long values from map click event, like so:

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    getAddress(event.latLng);
  });
}

function getAddress(location latlng) {
 var geocoder;
  var map;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also check the address against known deliverable addresses within the area.  This database is maintained by the USPS, who visits (practically) every address every single weekday.  Using a web-based API you could query the database and either get an automatic match or get a list of suggested matches.  I know this doesn't provide you a map, but in many cases, it can allow your clients to correct their address right there on the spot and can be very easy to implement and use.  Some services offer a Javascript implementation as well as an XML hook into the API.  If you're googling it, look for address verification webservice, or something similar.

I work for an address verification service called smartystreets.

Comment: thanks a lot, may you give me some sample that show me how can i use it?

Comment: Absolutely, there is a demo and an implementation guide on our [website](http://www.smartystreets.com/Products/LiveAddress-API/).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [reverse geocoding](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#ReverseGeocoding).Although your question is many questions in one and you should break it to smaller ones and ask them here also.